# VB Script or Batch file to pull specific lines of a text file to a seperate file

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I'm looking to have a program look through a text file for lines beginning with " F( "  and copy those lines to a separate text file, then delete anything after the close parentheses and add a fixed string of text before the line. (that string is " CALL EXTERN/DMIS,M,(DMIS_MACRO_FOR_FILTERING), ")

The full line I'm looking to copy looks like this.

```
F(Top_OD)=FEAT/CIRCLE,OUTER,CART,0,0,-0.2,0,0,1,0.99975
```

There will be multiple lines following the same format, as well as other lines I'm not interested in.

What I'd like to end up with would look like

```
CALL EXTERN/DMIS,M,(DMIS_MACRO_FOR_FILTERING),Top_OD
```

Adding to the difficulty, the length of the name I'm looking to copy can vary, and the number of commas in the line can change.

I'm not a programmer by trade, but I can normally piece together what I need from google, but this has me stymied for some probably obvious reason. Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
SOLVED- Below is the code

```
DIM FEATURE_LIST_FILENAME,MACRO_CALL_LIST
Dim RegEx : Set RegEx = New RegExp
Dim Matches
RegEx.IgnoreCase = True
RegEx.Global = FALSE
RegEx.Pattern = "F\((\w+)\)\="

FEATURE_LIST_FILENAME = "hardcoded filename"
MACRO_CALL_LIST = "hardcoded filename"
Set AN_INSTANCE_OF_A_FILESYSTEM_OBJECT =         CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set FILE_TO_READ =     AN_INSTANCE_OF_A_FILESYSTEM_OBJECT.OpenTextFile(FEATURE_LIST_FILENAME,1)

Set AN_INSTANCE_OF_A_FILESYSTEM_OBJECT =     CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set FILE_TO_WRITE = AN_INSTANCE_OF_A_FILESYSTEM_OBJECT.CreateTextFile     (MACRO_CALL_LIST,1)

'Set  = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
'Set FILE_TO_WRITE =      AN_INSTANCE_OF_A_FILESYSTEM_OBJECT.CreateTextFile(MACRO_CALL_LIST,1)

    Do Until FILE_TO_READ.AtEndOfStream

        CURRENT_LINE_IN_TEXT = FILE_TO_READ.ReadLine

    Set Matches = RegEx.Execute(CURRENT_LINE_IN_TEXT)
     If Matches.Count = 1 then FILE_TO_WRITE.Writeline "CALL EXTERN/DMIS,M,    (DMIS_MACRO_FOR_FILTERING)," + Matches(0).Submatches(0)


 'objFile.Writeline (CURENT_LINE_IN_TEXT)  


    Loop
FILE_TO_READ.Close
```

Comment: So the only part of the original line you are using is what is enclosed in the parentheses?

Comment: Piece together what you can, test it and then post it here with where you are stuck and what the actual and expected behavior is. That is how this site is supposed to work.

Comment: Basically all you are going to use is a `FOR /F` command and use the TOKENS and DELIMS options.  You just need the first two tokens and your delimiters will be both parentheses.  Use an `IF` command to check if the first token is equal to F.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple batch file

```
FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims=()" %%G IN (file.txt) DO (
     IF "%%G"=="F" echo CALL EXTERN/DMIS,M,(DMIS_MACRO_FOR_FILTERING^),%%H>>newfile.txt
)
```

Answer (score 0):

[Regular expression in VBScript](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yab2dx62(v=vs.84).aspx) may be a good way to do it. The regular expression pattern in this example will look for something that start with 'F(' + one or more word character including underscore + ')='. Nothing will be written if that pattern is not detected.

```
Set RegEx = New RegExp
RegEx.Pattern = "F\((\w+)\)\="

Do Until WScript.stdin.AtEndOfStream
    Set Matches = RegEx.Execute(WScript.stdin.ReadLine)
    If Matches.Count = 1 then WScript.echo "CALL EXTERN/DMIS,M,(DMIS_MACRO_FOR_FILTERING)," + Matches(0).Submatches(0)
Loop
```

You call the script from the command line by feeding in your input file like this:

```
cscript reg.vbs //nologo <in.txt >out.txt
```

Comment: I'm more comfortable using VB script than Batch, so I've been pursuing this, but I'm getting a "handle is invalid" error on this line

Comment: Got it figured out. Thanks for the help